# MongoDB query $in with $gt

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have three documents in a collection:

```
{
    ...
    houses: [{state: 'CA', quantity: 2}, {state: 'NY', quantity: 2}]
},
{
    ...
    houses: [{state: 'CA', quantity: 1}, {state: 'NY', quantity: 2}]
}
{
    ...
    houses: [{state: 'NY', quantity: 2}]
}
```

I'd like to write a query that matches the sentence "People with more than one house in either California or New York."  I know I can do something like this `{houses.state: {$in: ['CA', 'NY']}}`, but how can I combine that with `$gt` to get the match on both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to match multiple conditions within the *same* array element, you need to use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch):

```js
db.test.find({
    houses: {$elemMatch: {state: {$in: ['CA', 'NY']}, quantity: {$gt: 1}}}
})
```